# using only 'grep' command to get specific column

Tags: linux, csv, unix, grep, cat

This below shows this some lines of csv file, i want to get the results that only get the Population column with only using `grep` command.

```
id,Association,Population,Variant(s),Gene(s),PubMed
1,non-significant,Dutch,HLA-B40,HLA-B,1859103
2,non-significant,Dutch,HLA-DRB5,HLA-DRB5,1859103
3,non-significant,Finnish,APOB,APOB,8018664
4,significant,Finnish,APOC3,APOC3,8018664
5,significant,Finnish,E2/E3/E4,APOE,8018664
6,significant,French,I/D,ACE,8136829
```

results i want:

```
Dutch
Dutch
Finnish
Finnish
Finnish
French
```

The command i made for this problem was

```
 cat information.csv | grep -Eo '^([^,]*,){2}[^,]*'
```

which got results below

```
id,Association,Population
1,non-significant,Dutch
2,non-significant,Dutch
3,non-significant,Finnish
4,significant,Finnish
5,significant,Finnish
6,significant,French
```

how can i get rid of the rest of things without using `awk` `sed` or any other things?

Comment: can i ask why this pattern derives the results? I mean i can't understand perfectly about this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a GNU grep with a PCRE pattern:

```sh
grep -Po '^([^,]*,){2}\K[^,]*' file
```

Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `([^,]*,){2}` - two occurrences of any zero or more chars other than `,` and then a `,`
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than a comma.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question sir. Your answer really easy to understand for me!